# If $H$ and $K$ are subnormal subgroups in a supersoluble group, is their join also subnormal?

Tags: group-theory

> If $G$ is supersoluble, $H, K$ sn $G$, is it true $\langle H, K \rangle$ sn $G$?

Comment: This is certainly true for finite groups, a theorem of Wielandt.

Comment: @NickyHekster: That's correct, and without the need of supersolubility. But I can't find anywhere if this is true in the case of an arbitrary supersoluble group. And in $T$-groups, as well.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Maybe it requires some further study in textbooks, since there are a lot of results on this Subnormal Join Property (SJP). Perhaps the books of D.J.S. Robinson (A Course in The Theory of Groups or Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups) can help you further. I do not have any time to think about it now. But it is a good question. Found this, but does not help: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_satisfying_subnormal_join_property

Comment: According to https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_satisfying_subnormal_join_property the answer is yes. More generally, the property holds in groups with nilpotent derived subgroup. Robinson's book "A Course in the Theory of Groups" is given as reference.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you.